# How do I remove Madeye from my mac

Tags: html, terminal

I installed Madeye on my mac to try it out

`curl https://madeye.io/install | sh`

It is an awful piece of software, and i cant figure out how to remove it from my Mac, can one of you tell me how.  I've looked through their documentation, and there is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not an awful piece of software. It's very good actually, and does exactly what it claims.

You can always look at the script by omitting the last part where you ask SH to execute it and instead sending it to display with "more":

```
curl https://madeye.io/install | more
```

By reading the script, I see that it installs everything in ~/.madeye, so just remove that directory to get rid of it.

```
rm -rf ~./madeye
```

If you have maually added that directory to your path, you must remove it yourself.